# Unpartition my HDD in Windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning

I installed a new boot drive and my old HDD was partitioned in two.  I'm now quite frustrated as I try to merge these back into one 1TB volume instead of 600/300MB.

I've gotten as far as Disk Management.  I've formatted and deleted each volume.  But they still exist as two Unallocated spaces.

I've tried Formatting one of them, then extending it.  Which SEEMS to work, except it converts it to a Dynamic Disk, and still remains at about 600mb (even though it did find the other 300mb to extend from the wizard).  Plus it still has two different clickable chunks.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you need to keep any data on the disk, or can it be completely wiped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this from an elevated command prompt:

```
DISKPART
LIST DISK
SELECT DISK x    <-- Where x is the disk number for the 1TB drive
CLEAN
```

That will wipe all partition information from the disk and it will then appear in Disk Manager as a single, unformatted drive which you can then partition/format however you want.

**NOTE:** This will delete all data from the disk you select, so make sure this is what you want to do.